# Show a select field with options YES/NO without having a default option selected

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

I'm working on `angularjs` and I have a field that has two options YES/NO.

When someone will fill this field I need to show the two options but non of them is selected. So it will look like an empty value, but this empty value should not be an option. I tried to add `<option value="?"></option>` in the following code, but then the empty value is an option.
Any ideas?

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-if="obj.options.length > 0">
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="patientReportedSymptomsUI[key]" ng-disabled="$root.newVisit">
                            <option value="?"></option>
                            <option ng-repeat="option in obj.options">{{option}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Why is it a problem if the empty value is an option?

Comment: @Dan thanks for your reply. Because it refers to medical data and it needs to be yes or no.

Comment: I understand that there may be a good reason to require a value, but that's what form validation is for.  I don't think you can do any better than setting the model to `null`, which will start blank and remove the blank once a selection is made.  No need for `<option value="?></option>`.  Or you could make a custom select box.